# DAG dependencies, lazy loading

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

In Airflow when Python file gets imported, scheduler reads all of my dependencies. Because my dependencies are slow and calling native libraries, I would like to separate DAG schedule from actual tasks. I am planning to send tasks to the cloud.

What is the right design for Airflow to only import schedule and DAG definition, without importing task dependencies until they are actually used? What are pros, cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends heavily on your DAG design.

In general try to void any top level code both logic (reading variables, executing some functions etc) and imports. This can be done by using some form of lazy evaluation.

In case of imports you may try to bake your imports into a function that will be called only during execution (for example by creating custom operator or using python operator).

Comment: Tomasz, if you're using a `PythonOperator` and you import from a module the `import ...` in that module will be called as well, right? Do you recommend to have the `import ...` inside the function in that case?

Comment: That's what I would suggest. In this way all imports will happen only during execution not during DAG parsing or scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party.
As Tomasz sayd it depends heavily on your DAG structure, BTW, in order to avoid dependency resolution by the scheduler you can use a design pattern that "hide" your dependencies till execution time. If you are working with PythonOperator or PythonVenvOperator one approach is to move your import inside a support function inside the DAG.
[https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#:~:text=top&level&python&code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#:%7E:text=top&level&python&code)
Generally speaking if you want to call a Python function inside a whl package you can build a "wrapper function" inside your DAG that will import the dependencies and then call the actual function. From the PythonOperator you will call the "wrapper function" and not the actual target function directly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, your reply might help others. Btw, AirFlow deployment was successful althouth I did not solve this particular problem